# Is this tangential discussion in the comments too chatty (declined flags)?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, declined-flags, not-constructive

I ran into [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap), and found a bunch of comments which seem to not really be contributing much and should be removed (since it's basically just an extended discussion about what programmers should and shouldn't know), so I flagged each of them (as "too chatty", i.e. "no longer needed").

However, the flags were declined.

Was this a mistake by a moderator or do I just not understand what constitutes "too chatty"?

If they were declined (at least partly) because they were too highly voted... is this a good reason to decline it? Aren't non-constructive comments non-constructive regardless of their votes? Tangential comments tend to be vote magnets, not because it's useful as much as that it's an *opinion* someone's sharing that people agree with (or something along those lines).

[image]

(I didn't flag one of these - I think it was the first one, but that should probably be removed too)

Comment: If the comment is (highly) upvoted I wouldn't try to flag it. If it is deemed useful (hence the comment votes) and it isn't rude/abusive a moderator is not going to risk to delete a useful comment. At best use a custom flag explaining why the comment should be removed.

Comment: @rene I suspected the votes might have had something to do with it, but people sure do like to upvote tangential comments.

Comment: Sure. I only have success with removing upvoted comments if I flag the post and request to nuke all of them. But I really skip on these high-views, high votes, high-emotion posts because I have better things to do then to be called on meta for deleting a single valuable comment,...

Comment: Who can't not upvote a comment that mentions unicorns and waffles?

Comment: @JonClements dangit.  You tricked my bot's regex for "interesting comments."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I didn't flag one of these - I think it was the first one, but that should probably be removed too

I assumed that every single comment but the first one being flagged meant someone wanted the first to stick around, and I felt if it were to stay then the comments disagreeing should too.

Since that’s now been clarified, though… consider them gone!

Because they are.

Comment: I didn't really expect that to affect whether the flags get declined... If all of them are no longer needed (regardless of the intention behind the flagging), wouldn't it be better to mark them as helpful and delete the first comment as well?

Comment: I think the first two comments are perfectly fine and would have preserved them. Someone makes a good, relevant point, and then someone makes a counter-argument. Nothing excessively noisy about that. I guess I won't override your vote to delete them the first day on the job, though.

Comment: @CodyGray: The first comment is pretty much just saying that the question is important. I think the question itself is probably enough.